# Trouble with accessing Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud Firestore and am having some problems accessing a value in a simple database.

[Here is how the database is structured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5wcw.png)

This is the code I am using to access the "basementER-status" field in the database.

```
//current status value is pulled from database
  function getRawStatus ()
  {
    return db.collection("rooms").doc("roomsDoc").get().then(function(doc) {
      console.log(doc.data()); 
      console.log(doc.data().basementER-status);
      return doc.data().basementER-status;
    });
  }
```

For the first console.log, this is printed to the console:

```
{1ER-status: 0, 2ER-status: 0, basementER-status: 0}
1ER-status: 0
2ER-status: 0
basementER-status: 0
__proto__: Object
```

This is the correct doc that needs to be brought from the database, so I know that part of my code is right.

However, the second console.log prints NaN to the console.

What is happening here? I don't understand. I've accessed fields like this before in cloud firestore and it has always worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of the way JavaScript parses your statement.  This line:

```
console.log(doc.data().basementER-status);
```

Is actually performing a mathematical subtraction between `doc.data().basementER` and the value of the variable `status`.  That's not what you want.

If you want the value of a field with JavaScript operators or other special characters in it, you will have to use a different syntax:

```
const data = doc.data();
console.log(data['basementER-status']);
```

The square brackets let you provide an arbitrary string to look up the name property in the object.

Answer (score 2):

For your second `console.log` statement, you are trying to access a specific parameter in an object, so you should use this:

```
     console.log(doc.data()["basementER-status"]);
```

For more info, go here: [firestore adding data link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)